# onNewIntent Method is not called when NFC Tag is scanned

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, intentfilter, ndef

When I scan a NFC tag with my phone the `onNewIntent()` method is not called. It is just opening a bar where I can select the application which should handle the scan, but even if I select my application there the `onNewIntent()` method is not executed.

I already tried to put the NFC tag handling in an extra method called `performTagOperations()`,

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView mtv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mtv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        mtv1.setText("Hallo");
        performTagOperations(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Intent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mtv1.setText("Intent");
        performTagOperations(intent);
    }

    private void performTagOperations(Intent intent){
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            Log.d("NFC",tag.toString());
            Parcelable[] rawMessages =
                    intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            if (rawMessages != null) {
                NdefMessage[] messages = new NdefMessage[rawMessages.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < rawMessages.length; i++) {
                    messages[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMessages[i];
                }
                // Process the messages array.
                for (NdefMessage n:
                        messages) {
                    Log.d("NFC", n.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        </activity>
    </application>
```

nfc_tech_filter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
        <!-- class name -->
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

It should execute the `onNewIntent()` method when the tag is scanned but it does not execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You registered to receive the NFC intent `android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED` in your manifest. However, in `performTagOperations()` you expect to receive `android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED`(`NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED`). Consequently, the code within that IF statement will never execute. You will have to change that to

```
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
}
```

Or even better, register an intent filter for an NDEF data type appropriate for your tag.

Also note that `onNewIntent()` will only be called when your activity is already running. If your activity is created by the NFC intent, you can obtain the intent in e.g. `onCreate()` instead.